# Bison report shift reduce conflict but how can I locate them?

Tags: parsing, bison, shift-reduce-conflict

I'm working on a bison parser with most of the features of an OOP language and now bison complains that there are some shift/reduce conflicts. I got:

```
conflicts: 21 shift/reduce
```

The problem is that it does not tell me where they are. Does anyone know how to locate there conflicts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the manual page about [command line options](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Bison-Options.html#Bison-Options) you will notice one called `--report` and another called `--report-file`. These two tells Bison to create a report file of the specified name, that among other things should include more information about conflicts.